# error LNK2019 in connecting C++ program to database

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using visual C++ 2010 and I am starting up a project need to connect to the database

I started by including

1. C:\Program Files\boost_1_55_0
2. C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.3\include

to C++->General, also

1. C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 1.1.3\lib\opt

to Linker->General and set Linker->Input mysqlcppconn.lib

At last I moved mysqlcppconn.dll and libmysql.dll to my project under the debug folder.

It still has a LINK2019 error. What is the problem?

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __thiscall sql::SQLException::getSQLState(void)const " (__imp_?getSQLState@SQLException@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) referenced in function __catch$_main$0
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall sql::SQLException::getErrorCode(void)const " (__imp_?getErrorCode@SQLException@sql@@QBEHXZ) referenced in function __catch$_main$0
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z) referenced in function _main
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__get_driver_instance referenced in function _main
```

The following is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mysql_connection.h>  
#include <cppconn/driver.h>  
#include <cppconn/exception.h>  
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>  
#include <cppconn/statement.h> 

using namespace std;  

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try {  
        sql::Driver *driver;  
        sql::Connection *con;  
        sql::Statement *stmt;  
        sql::ResultSet *res;  
        sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt;

        driver = get_driver_instance();  
        con = driver->connect("localhost", "user_name", "password");  

        con->setSchema("test"); 

        con->setClientOption("characterSetResults", "utf8");
        stmt = con->createStatement();  
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * from user");  

        while (res->next())   
        {  

            int id = res->getInt("ID");
            cout<<id<<endl;


        } 
        delete res;  
        delete stmt;
        delete con;  
    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {  

        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;  
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line "  
            << __LINE__ << endl;  
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();  
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();  
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;  
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you mixing 32bit/64bit or dynamic/static linked libs maybe? Afaik those symbols should be in the sql lib so if the linker doesn't get them it has to be something like that..

Comment: I downloaded the 64 bit verison of C++ connector and mysql server and I am running a win32 console application, will it be the problem?

Comment: Likely. 32bit and 64bit do not mix.

Comment: That's mean i should download all 32bit version of connector and mysql server even my computer is 64bit, am I right?